# Codeigniter : Multiple form fields having same name posting less than the actual number of input fields present inside the form

Tags: forms, codeigniter

I request someone to improve the question :

I have a form with multiple fields having same name.
While I check the number of specific input fields in the the form it shows a value suppose 300.
But when I create a foreach loop basing on that input field the loop iterates less than the number of times the input field is present.

Here is my code to give you a braod Idea.

I've created form fields dynamically basing on the data.

So view contains:

```
foreach($customers as $customer) { 
?>
    <input type="hidden" name="customer_id[]" value="<?php echo $customer['customer_id']; ?>" > 
    //and Other input fields
```

In my model I'm cheking the number of times it is posted and then creating a for each loop.

Model:

```
$customer_ids   =   $this->input->post('customer_id');

foreach ($customer_ids as $key => $customer_id) 
{ 
    Insert data in the database
}
```

The issue is the number of input fields are 297 but the form iterates only for 125 times.

If I post some data after 125 number row it's not getting inserted

Comment: `var_dump($this->input->post('customer_id'));` are you submitting the form via `ajax`?

Comment: I have already tested it but it displays ids till 119. I have 297 IDs.

Comment: have you checked your `php.ini` try setting the `post_max_size` to `0 (zero)`

Comment: The post_max_size is 8M, I've not changed it as the issue was solved by increasing maxmax_input_vars 1000 to 3000.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of test, check, experiment and research I found that max_input_vars is making the problem. As I've recently updated to ubuntu 14.04 I think the maxmax_input_vars has been changed. I changed maxmax_input_vars in the .htaccess and it works fine.

But I have one confusion. I have another form which is sending the same type of post. But while my maxmax_input_vars was 1000. It was working.